# How can I keep state of data from provider

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, provider, state-management

I just wanna update my data when I press Apply Button, But provider does not allow it. When I update my checkbox value state all of my provider data is updating. How can I avoid this

[Filter Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQyRQ.png)

https://gist.github.com/MehmetAtabey/bc7ab87dec3c42f4d46fbd8f9d9f07c9

Comment: Use a different class to save the state of the app usually called ViewModel because it links the View (ProductListFilterSelectionScreen) and Model (Product) together. Add in there all your logic, not in the view.

Comment: How can I do that I mean if you look at my code I was accutualy cast filters List to another list which is sublist but when I manipulate the sublist it changes all of my provider data. How is possible. It's a different list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood well your question you should add to subfilters a copy of your Filter, not the same element.
Because Dart uses by default object references, you are referencing the same object.

Create for you filter a "clone" method:

```
class Filter {
  final String filterName;
  final String filterGroupName;
  int count = 0;
  bool isSelected = false;
  Filter(this.filterGroupName, this.filterName);
  
  factory Filter.clone(Filter source){
    Filter f = Filter(source.filterGroupName, source.filterName);
    f.count = source.count;
    f.isSelected = source.isSelected;
    return f;
  }
}
```

When you create the sub list array, use the "clone" method to add the object to the new list:

```
List<Filter> temp = widget.filters.where((element) => element.filterGroupName == widget.filterGroupName).toList();

widget.subFilters = List<Filter>();    
temp.forEach((el)=>widget.subFilters.add(Filter.clone(el)));
```